# Transaction Manager bean in jboss 7

Tags: spring, jboss7.x, ibm-mq

We are deploying MDB in jboss 7 using IBM MQ as messaging provider. We are migrating (MDB EAR) from IBM WAS Application server to Jboss keeping messaging in IBM MQ.
As part of migration we need to change transaction manager from IBM Web sphere App server to JBoss specific transaction manager.

As you can see below wsTxManager bean specific to web sphere. We need Jboss specific bean. Can you any one help me on this.?

```
<bean id="wsTxManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebSphereTransactionManagerFactoryBean" />

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="userTransactionName">
            <null />
        </property>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="wsTxManager" />
    </bean>
```

Logs:

```
7c11372: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77c11372]; startup date [Tue Feb 20 17:21:42 SGT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[2018-02-20 17:21:42,674] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [vfs:/content/our_app.ear/our_app.jar/beanRefContext.xml]
[2018-02-20 17:21:42,976] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@77c11372]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@406aa4b4
[2018-02-20 17:21:42,981] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@406aa4b4: defining beans [businessBeanFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
[2018-02-20 17:21:43,000] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@66b1b69e: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@66b1b69e]; startup date [Tue Feb 20 17:21:43 SGT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
[2018-02-20 17:21:43,000] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [app-ejb-context.xml]
[2018-02-20 17:21:43,034] [default-threads - 12] [INFO ] [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@406aa4b4: defining beans [businessBeanFactory]; root of factory hierarchy
[2018-02-20 17:21:43,045] [default-threads - 29] [INFO ] [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7e92809d: display name [org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@7e92809d]; startup date [Tue Feb 20 17:21:43 SGT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with JBoss:

```
<bean id="containerTransaction" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:/TransactionManager</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <ref local="containerTransaction"/>
    </property>
    <property name="userTransactionName">
        <value>java:jboss/UserTransaction</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: But we don't have java:/TransactionManager,java:jboss/UserTransaction JNDI configured in our JBoss. Is that ok?

Comment: Yes it is ok. java:/TransactionManager "means", that you use the transaction manager from JBoss and jboss/UserTransaction is a link for the UserTransaction.

Comment: We placed above mentioned beans in our app-ejb-context.xml file . But after deploying we are getting below log messages continuously. I added log info in question itself, please check.

Comment: Dear @awagenhoffer, at the end of the logger   [DEBUG] [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] - Resuming suspended transaction   ----
Can we try to stop this resumption?

Comment: Could you post debug log?

Comment: It is normal, if you have for example an inner transaction. Are there any errors in log?

Comment: Thanks @awagenhoffer,